# Clonezilla's checksums file verification using signature with gpg extension

Tags: linux, gnupg, clonezilla, digital-signature, verification

There are [CHECKSUMS.TXT](http://clonezilla.org/downloads/stable/data/CHECKSUMS.TXT) and [CHECKSUMS.TXT.gpg](http://clonezilla.org/downloads/stable/data/CHECKSUMS.TXT.gpg) files available on the Clonezilla Live's [official download page](http://clonezilla.org/downloads.php).

However I cannot verify its signature by usual verify command:

```
$ gpg --verify --keyring ./CHECKSUMS.TXT.gpg ./CHECKSUMS.TXT
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: the signature could not be verified.
Please remember that the signature file (.sig or .asc)
should be the first file given on the command line.
```

and

```
$ gpg --verify ./CHECKSUMS.TXT.gpg
gpg: no signed data
gpg: can't hash datafile: No data
```

How can I verify the CHECKSUMS.TXT file's integrity using  CHECKSUMS.TXT.gpg file that is available on Clonezilla Live's official web site?

Comment: Have you tried `gpg --verify ./CHECKSUMS.TXT.gpg ./CHECKSUMS.TXT`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clonezilla uses a detached signature. The [GPG manual](https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/x135.html#AEN160) has a paragraph on detached signatures, which shows how to create them, and how to verify them.

The correct command line to verify such signatures is `gpg --verify ./CHECKSUMS.TXT.gpg ./CHECKSUMS.TXT`.

I've never before seen the `gpg --verify --keyring ./CHECKSUMS.TXT.gpg ./CHECKSUMS.TXT` line, which attempts to verify a signed file (containing both the signature and the original document) `./CHECKSUMS.txt` while adding the keys in the `./CHECKSUMS.TXT.gpg` to the keyring.